# How to get field name in document when create a new document in subcollection

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi3

I made a project to scan a face using firebase as a database by setting it in the hardware that if scanning a face and then the name is equal to this person, it will send data to subcollection. In the database now it's sorted like this collection > document > subcollection > document > subcollection > document (create) I want to get a name like this image below when i create a document [code](https://codefile.io/f/eIZOUuQpjrEN2unkzNj5)

```
if name == classNames[matchIndex]:
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'teacher').document(u'AllUser').collection(u'profile').document(name).collection(u'time').document()
            my_data = {"timeStamp": SERVER_TIMESTAMP}
            doc_ref.set(my_data)
```

[image: my database]

or how to get a reference to a document then get a field name in document to new document in subcollection

```
if name == classNames[matchIndex]:
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'teacher').document(u'AllUser').collection(u'profile').document(name).collection(u'time').document()
            my_data = ({"timeStamp": SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
               "name":... #field name in document
                })
            doc_ref.set(my_data)
```

Comment: As you are already querying using name in doc_ref, why can't you use the name to set that there ?

Comment: There that you mean where is it can you give an example please ? I have try in my_data name: name but it a name that scan not a name in field of document

Comment: Here take a look at this [**`snippet`**](https://codefile.io/f/awuR3Tpo1wzko7nuMun0)

Comment: Hi does that solved your issue ?

Comment: It error NameError: name 'document_id' is not defined here my code please take a look [code](https://codefile.io/f/eIZOUuQpjrEN2unkzNj5)

Comment: based on your shared snippet it seems that you are trying to fetch the Firestore document corresponding to the name variable and update its fields. You can use the where() method to query the time subcollection for documents that have the name field equal to the current name value, and then update the first document that matches. I have updated my previous snippet with the replacement code. Take a look at it.

Comment: It error say AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'empty'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252766/discussion-between-trures-and-rohit-kharche).